# INSERT INTO using SET in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My first post so bear with me.

I need to restore a DB Table from a backup.  I have cleaned the SQL up so I only have the the DROP TABLE, CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO commands.  The query is failing when I run it in MYSQl on my server.

The error message is....

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id='2', 
unitid='1', 
optionname='Baby Chair', 
customtype='0', 
customfeild' at line 3
```

The query is.....

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jos_resman_options`;
CREATE TABLE `jos_resman_options` 
(
`id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`unitid` int(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`optionname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

`customtype` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`customfeild` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

`moreinformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

`totaloptions` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',

`minvalue` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`maxvalue` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`formobject` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`priceoption` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`taxfree` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`compulsory` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`istax` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`isinsure` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=75;

INSERT INTO `jos_resman_options` 
VALUES 
id='2', 
unitid='1', 
optionname='Baby Chair', 
customtype='0', 
customfeild='', 
moreinformation='Baby Chair', 
totaloptions='0', 
price='0.00', 
minvalue='1', 
maxvalue='2', 
formobject='1', 
enabled='1', 
priceoption='2', 
taxfree='1', 
compulsory='0', 
istax='0', 
isinsure='0';
```

---

The table is created, When the CREATE TABLE part runs on it's own there is no error message. I only see the error message when the INSERT INTO part of the query runs.
The INSERT INTO data is directly from a backup of the database and so the data SHOULD be OK??

Many Thanks for any input

Have Tried all of the suggestions...Changing the Auto INCREMENT to DEFAULT Field, Put in the Brackets, All of them fail with error messages. Here's the latest error message... Thanks again all.!

```
Error
SQL query:

INSERT INTO  `jos_resman_options` 
SET unitid =  '1',
optionname =  'Baby Chair',
customtype =  '0',
customfeild =  '',
moreinformation =  'Baby Chair',
totaloptions =  '0',
price =  '0.00',
minvalue =  '1',
maxvalue =  '2',
formobject =  '1',
enabled =  '1',
priceoption =  '2',
taxfree =  '1',
compulsory =  '0',
istax =  '0',
isinsure =  '0'

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxvalue='2',
formobject='1', 
enabled='1', 
priceoption='2', 
taxfree='1',' at line 12
```

Comment: You need parenthesis: INSERT INTO `jos_resman_options` 
VALUES( 
id='2', 
unitid='1', 
optionname='Baby Chair', 
customtype='0', 
customfeild='', 
moreinformation='Baby Chair', 
totaloptions='0', 
price='0.00', 
minvalue='1', 
maxvalue='2', 
formobject='1', 
enabled='1', 
priceoption='2', 
taxfree='1', 
compulsory='0', 
istax='0', 
isinsure='0');

Comment: Add parenthesis around the values section.  VALUES (
id='2', .....  )

Comment: also if you have autoincremented id why to add them manually just dont insert id values.

Comment: Thanks!  I presume the ID value is there because it has already been assigned in the database and I think it ties up with another table somewhere. I'll try it though. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `jos_resman_options` 
VALUES (
id='2', 
unitid='1', 
optionname='Baby Chair', 
customtype='0', 
customfeild='', 
moreinformation='Baby Chair', 
totaloptions='0', 
price='0.00', 
minvalue='1', 
maxvalue='2', 
formobject='1', 
enabled='1', 
priceoption='2', 
taxfree='1', 
compulsory='0', 
istax='0', 
isinsure='0');
```

Answer (score 0):

try  to delete id fields becouse id was defined AutoNumber.
So you can not insert a value because it handles the database engine, if you delete the columba will tell you different amount of columns to insert, then try putting id = DEFAULT or omit the id field

Comment: Thanks!  I presume the ID value is there because it has already been assigned in the database and I think it ties up with another table somewhere. I'll try it though. Cheers

Comment: looking for mysql documentation i found  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/error-handling.html in the 1064 error say casting error , try in de customfeild field set other value 
Regards